# how to get and show date and save into the Database in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I try to create a Human resource application using Fullcalendar , users must insert their work hours for each day on it. By clicking on a day a modal (dialog) will open . i was wondering how can i  : 
1 : get the date user click and show it above the modal (in modal titre)?
2 : how can save that day with other information into DB ?
(I am using bootstrap)

This is my html code :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" aria-hidden="true"><form role="form" method="post" action="#"> (Simple form elements) </form></div>
```

and this is my Fullcallendar :

```
 <script>

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // Italian languge 
        lang: 'it',
        // Saiz 
        height: 600,
        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            // Changing BG color
            $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
            //create window here
            $('#myModal').modal();
        },
        header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'next',
        },
        editable: true,
    });</script>
```

Comment: Isn't this the most basic usage of Javascript PHP and MySQL?

Comment: it is ... but i have got confused since i started using fullcalendar and also i am new in programming. so if you can please help me ...